# Show Only Most Current Entries In PowerBI Table Pulling From Multiple Data Sources

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Relative Novice with PowerBI. I have a Table visualization that pulls from several SharePoint lists and summarizes actions for audit report recommendations.  Most recommendation actions are completed on a single date so have a single Date Completed entry, but some recommendations require more than one action over time so have multiple Date Completed entries.  I would like my PowerBI Table to only show the most recent Date Completed for any Final Report Recommendations with multiple Date Completed entries (and just the one date for Final Report Recommendation with only a single Date Completed entry).  Here's the problem, however: The Final Report Number entry is taken from a SharePoint List called 'Audit Cases' and the Rec Number is taken from a SharePoint list called 'Recommendations' while the Date Completed is taken from a SharePoint list called "Follow Up Journal'.  The attached image shows a part of my Table as it currently displays - you can see the multiple entries for Report GAO-20-110 Rec Numbers 11 & 12.  I would like the Table to only show the most recent entry for those Recs, for instance: only 1/4/2022 for Rec 11.  I've tried some measures in this forum for Max Date, etc. but they don't seem to work when the Report and Recommendation and Completed Date info is pulled from different tables.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in Advance[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2LpE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the date column in Values and choose Latest.[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works to remove most of the earlier entries, but there are still some that remain... I can't see what the differences are in those rows vs the rows that where earlier entries don't show.  You pointed me in the right direction!